# Facebook Graph API  - get ID for a URL?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, reliability

This seems like a pretty obvious, basic thing to expect from the [Graph API](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facebook_Platform#Graph_API), but I'm having serious difficulty with it. All I want to do is get the ID for any particular URL. They have a method for this:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/?ids=http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0117500/
```

And that works great. But if I try another URL, say for my blog,

```
https://graph.facebook.com/?ids=http://dusda.vox.com
```

it doesn't give me back a numerical ID like all of the examples do. Instead, this:

```
{"http:\/\/dusda.vox.com":{"id":"http:\/\/dusda.vox.com"}}
```

If I try to use that "id", I get jack (probably because the query string looks impossible to parse):

```
Request: https://graph.facebook.com/http://dusda.vox.com/likes
Response: {"id":"http:\/\/dusda.vox.com\/likes"}
```

So what's up with this? Is the Graph API just selectively reliable, or am I misunderstanding something? I've tried it on URLs that I *know* are popular on Facebook, too, and I've gotten mixed results.

Comment: Old question, still no solution? I tried cnn.com, works fine in the debugger, but does not return the ID using the API...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The ID is given by Facebook only to pages which have a fbshare/like button. Else the API returns the number of shares and the request URL.

Comment: https://graph.facebook.com/?id=http://www.huffingtonpost.com/2011/06/14/new-york-mercatus-center-least-free-state_n_876616.html has a Like button but the link still gives back limited information. Both pages has a fb:app_id in the <head> section.

Comment: Is this behaviour documented somewhere?

Answer (score 10):

Try [FQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facebook_Query_Language)  for this;

```
http://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=select%20url%2C%20id%2C%20type%2C%20site%20from%20object_url%20where%20url%20%3D%20%22http%3A%2F%2Fkriek.hu%2F%22
```

returns:

```
{
   "data": [
      {
         "url": "http://kriek.hu/",
         "id": 497425470154,
         "type": "link",
         "site": "kriek.hu"
      }
   ]
}
```

For more information, see *[object_url](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/object_url/)*.

I hope it helps!

Comment: With this you get id which is useful. +1

Comment: I don't know about you, but the ID I get is not valid (not even in the debugger).

Comment: FQL is being deprecated.

Answer (score 4):

If I use the facebook object debugger page I can  scrape every url, for example:

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=ddnl.de

The page give me back an url with ID and so I can get every needed parameters.

In this case https://graph.facebook.com/10150164108649475

But I don't get this ID or url with FQL or otherwise?

Answer (score 3):

Very old question, but here's what I found works for me as none of the answers here really resolved my issue:

If you have a custom object tied to a url, the method suggested by Pepe only gives the id FB assigns to the url where type=link. (Which is not tied to any comments)

In my case, I need my custom object id so that I could pull associated comments from it.  You can get the object id using FQL by doing a select on 'comments_fbid' from the 'link_stat' table.  (This will return the object id even if no comments have been added so it should work for other cases)

[api.facebook.com](http://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?query=select%20comments_fbid%20from%20link_stat%20where%20url%20=%20%22http://www.localmenu.it/listing/show/1%22)

Answer (score 2):

At this time no of the suggested solutions work for all urls. Only the Debugger is able to get the Graph ID correctly

For example

Debugger:
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.amazon.de%2Fgp%2Fproduct%2F3810510793%2F

For URL:
www.amazon.de/gp/product/3442465583/

Result:
https://graph.facebook.com/10150771435736113

```
{
   "url": "http://www.amazon.de/dp/3810510793/ref=tsm_1_fb_lk",
   "type": "book",
   "title": "Die unwahrscheinliche Pilgerreise des Harold Fry: Roman",
   "image": [
      {
         "url": "http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51I4E81xrRL._SL160_.jpg"
      }
   ],
   "description": "Die unwahrscheinliche Pilgerreise des Harold Fry: Roman",
   "site_name": "Amazon.de",
   "updated_time": "2012-12-19T16:54:27+0000",
   "id": "10150771435736113",
   "application": {
      "id": "164734381262",
      "name": "Amazon",
      "url": "https://www.facebook.com/apps/application.php?id=164734381262"
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem here, I was trying to get the same data IMDB gets. After almost bang my head against the wall, I decided to look at the facebook's js function. And look what I get, the explanation is on the link.

[Getting limited data from a page which has a Facebook ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13022500/getting-limited-data-from-a-page-which-has-a-facebook-id/13036022#13036022)

Peace