# Problems Sharing my website made with laravel in Facebook

Tags: performance, laravel, laravel-routing, laravel-blade, laravel-socialite

I have this page made in Laravel:
[papirolasvirtual.com.mx](http://papirolasvirtual.com.mx)

The problem is when I share my website link to facebook it doesn't show my website's logo: A magnifying glass appears.

Does anyone know how that problem can be solved?
Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I set a website image that will show as preview on facebook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6693499/how-can-i-set-a-website-image-that-will-show-as-preview-on-facebook)

Answer (score 1):

You need to add Facebook Open Graph META Tags o the head tag on your laravel app on `layouts.app`file
you can review the documentation of facebook

here's the link
`https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/opengraph`