# Change Preview of Webpage Link

Tags: html

I created a new webpage that has a blog. How can I get an appealing preview of the website as I see when I share links from NY Times and other sites?  This is my site [www.denisejames.dev](http://www.denisejames.dev) This is the current view

[image]

I would like to add a picture and a title.

I am told that this is a duplicate answer even though I did not mention facebook at all and the recommended answer is only for facebook. The answer helps to let me know, the preview is different for each app I post a link into.  Hopefully this will help others using preview for the first time. I see previews in twitter, what app. I was not aware they are different for each app for the same link.

Comment: can you be more specific, what are you trying to do?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I set a website image that will show as preview on Facebook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6693499/how-can-i-set-a-website-image-that-will-show-as-preview-on-facebook)

Comment: i think this can help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/43154489/3836908

Comment: Thanks  @sanojLawrence. These links help. I did not realize they are specific to facebook twitter, awesom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are sharing your website on Facebook. When you share a link on Facebook you will get a preview of the image that the website has in the top menu. You have a title on the top part of your website, but The New York Times has a svg instead. Svg is Scalable Vector Graphics, so it's a graphic symbol. Once you replace that text you have (Denise James) with an image, a gif, a svg element  or something similar, you'll have the preview too.