# How do I clear the opengraph's image tag proxy cache?

Tags: facebook, proxy, facebook-opengraph

I have a page with og tags (including a `source` and an `image` - a youtube-like video view page).
I've replaced the image the og:image tag points to, to another image by the same name. However, when using the facebook linter/debugger, the image shown is the old image, while clicking the image itself, opens and shows the new image.

Facebook uses some kind of a proxy cache for the content of the image - how can I clear it without changing the name of the image file ?

Answer (score 4):

[This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5776567/facebook-open-graph-not-clearing-cache) gives an answer.

To reiterate (in case thread goes down),

1. Go to http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug
2. Enter the URL (of the page that holds your og meta tags) and include the query data:  fbrefresh=CAN_BE_ANYTHING

e.g. `http://www.example.com/mypage.html?fbrefresh=CAN_BE_ANYTHING`

Comment: Doesn't seem to work any longer ? Just tried that and it scrapped a different page, and didn't refresh the meta image of the same name (note that my image was on a CDN, and I invalidated the CDN cache)

Answer (score 1):

Using the debugger/linter should force a full recache. I suspect the caching you're seeing is in your browser. Have you tried emptying your cache or using incognito mode?

If that doesn't work (and depending on how much traffic you're getting) it might have something to do with the names being the same - but I don't think this should be the case. Try replacing the image with another with a different name, hit the URL in the debugger so FB receives the new one, then swap back to the one you want. Kinda janky, but will probably do what you want.

Comment: If you have an image thats cached then renaming seems to be the way to go - even if its a pain.