# Facebook caching issue

Tags: facebook, caching, facebook-opengraph

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Facebook Open Graph not clearing cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5776567/facebook-open-graph-not-clearing-cache)

Why do we still see Facebook caching issues even after adding open graph meta tags to the page. Do we have any solution to this problem? It keeps occurring quite often. It works after using the URL linter. But this cannot be always used as a solution to the problem. Please help.

Comment: i know that URL linter/debugger will clear the cache. But is that the only solution that's available? Are the open graph tags not supposed to fix this issue at first place?

Comment: You can do it programatically as well by making a post request to graph URL.
This might help http://alfanso.com/asking-facebook-to-clear-cached-data/