# og:image and facebook linter are showing 2 different images

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

I changed the og:image being used for this post a week ago and the old one still shows up when you check the url in linter. The url is the same in the meta tag but the pic IS different. Could it be a FB Cache issue? For a week? If so, Is there a way to clear fb cache?

http://blogs.edweek.org/edweek/Bridging-Differences/2013/02/dear_alfie_i_follow_your.html
Image that should appear

But you'll see linter shows the old image still (which was too small). I was under the impression that linter will refresh the cache. I did read to put a totally different image url in there and then switch it back but it didn't work. When I changed the url, that did get updated but then when I put the url back to the other file name. The old image STILL displays even though the image in that url is different

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, running the lint checker/debugger on a URL used to cause Facebook to update the og:image. I just wrestled with this and solved the problem by appending "?1" to the URL I provide for the image. I ran it through the lint checker again and Facebook updated to the new image.

Apache ignores the query parameters on static files. I don't know about other web servers. If dummy query parameters are a problem, you might try changing the image's filename.

I suspect that Facebook has changed something about their caching. Thanks for sparing me the pain of waiting for cache expiration by having done that experiment yourself.

Answer (score 0):

> Facebook has a tool called [Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) (formerly known as URL Linter).(...) We can use this tool for any url and it fetches the latest title,
>   description, excerpt and other stuff that will be shown while sharing
>   the link. If you use an already shared URL with this tool then
>   Facebook fetches the latest content, and also updates it cache with
>   the latest content.

More info [here](http://umairj.com/146/how-to-clear-facebook-shares-cache/). I also found that you can try with using `fbrefresh` parameter in this debugger - [Facebook Open Graph not clearing cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5776567/facebook-open-graph-not-clearing-cache)

Comment: Thanks but the debugger is what I'm using which is displaying the old image even though the url that the debugger is showing is showing the new image when you go there. I did try adding fbrefresh and I'm the admin of the app but it's still not getting refreshed with the new content

Comment: @BrianJohnPercival Yeah, my answer was stupid. ^^ I realized now that after doing some research I found many people writing it worked and when I got back here to I forgot that you tried it. ^^