# Facebook open grach og:description cache issue

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

I'm trying Facebook open graph, and I want to assign og:description dynamically when a user share my page,
     and it's determined by my php.

```
<meta name="og:title" content="test1" />  
<meta name="og:description" content="<?php  echo $_REQUEST['parm'] ?>" />  
<meta name="og:image" content="http://nuphoto.com.tw/titleapp4.png" />  
<meta name="og:url" content="http://nuphoto.com.tw/share/easygo_bruce.php" />
```

However, it always caches the previous result, and it doesn't change.
     I googled the solution , but all of them didn't work.
     Here're my trials.

- Go to https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug
      and enter my url. 
      it works, but I need to change my page dynamically. so it's not suitable for me.
- Follow [How to update facebook open graph image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15671118/how-to-update-facebook-open-graph-image)

  ```
  $.post(
  'https://graph.facebook.com',
  {
      id: 'http://www.example.com/my/share/url/',
  scrape: true
  },
  function(response){
  console.log(response);
   });
  ```

  it didn't work, and showed error.

  ```
  FB.getLoginStatus() called before calling FB.init(). all.js:53
  Object {url: "http://example.com/mytest.php", type: "website", title: "test, image: Array[1], description: "XXX"…}
  ```

  - Someone said add `v=XXX&fbrefresh=XXX` may help, but it still fails for me.

  `https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=example.com&fbrefresh&v=xxxx`

Please help me , I already spent hours of work....

Answer (score 0):

None of those solutions will work for you, Why?

Facebook debugger scrapes your URL and get the static HTML (`meta`) of your pages.
**Facebook BOT is not a user with a session!**, it scrapes your page meta tags, refresh its cache and get out that's all

```
<meta name="og:description" content="<?php  echo $_REQUEST['parm']; ?>" />
```

`$_REQUEST['parm']` is what the current user/session see and set, while the debugger doesn't have a session or `$_REQUEST['parm']` set.

sincerely, you can't change `og:image` dynamically according to the current session.

Answer (score 0):

In fact , what I want is to make a dynamically FB description, I will show different coupon code for each FB sharing post. So I need to pass the coupon code to description. I can't find the correct way. Using get string in sharer.php?u=http://example.com.tw?coupon=DXSCVV didn't work.

Finally, I use php to generate a file dynamically, which this file has the file name of coupon, such as DXSCVV.htm.  sharer.php ->sharer.php?u=http://example.com.tw/DXSCVV.htm

It works. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

i had the same issue but i solved that by adding this code to force facebook to scrape my page it worked for me

```
FB.api("", 'post', { id: 'YourLinkToShare', scrape: 'true' }, function () {"YourShareMethodHERE'; });
```

try it and let me know ;)