# Facebook like button shows old image, even after reload

Tags: javascript, facebook-like

The user goes to a page with image A. If he presses the Facebook like button, it displays image A next to the url. He then navigates to an edit page, changes the image to image B, and then reloads the original page. The page now displays image B. He presses the like button and it's still showing image A.

I have

```
 <meta property="og:image" content = "image_b" />
```

Answer (score 0):

This [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5776567/facebook-open-graph-not-clearing-cache) will give you the answer.
Facebook catches pages. You basically would need to have that cache refreshed in order for your page to show a different image. Since this can only be done manually I would suggest using a form variable in your header so that facebook caches more then one page/url.