# Description not posting with story on Facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

My story is posting on FB just fine, but the description isn't part of what gets posted.  What I'm getting instead is the URL to the page with the meta tags.  There's some redundancy in the examples below, but I don't think that matters.

Is there some reason that the description wouldn't post?

```
        var accessToken = (string)Session["accessToken"];
        var args = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        args["appnamespace"] = "myapp";
        args["object_name"] = "myobname";
        args["myobname"] = "/social/post/facebook.aspx?id=qwerdefre";
        args["action"] = "Earned";
        args["access_token"] = accessToken;
        args["description"] = "Praesent neque velit, ultrices vitae purus eget";
        args["image"] = "/img/thisimage.png";
        args["link"] = "/pages/welcome";
        args["title"] = "The Title";
        FacebookClient client = new FacebookClient(accessToken);
        client.AppId = Configuration.Social.FacebookConsumerKey;
        dynamic result = client.Post("/me/myapp:myobname", args);
        Response.Write(result);
        Response.Write("<p/>");
```

Below are the meta tags from the Open Graph page:

```
    <meta property="fb:app_id" content="11123213" />
    <meta property="og:title" content="The Title" />
    <meta property="og:image" content="/img/thisimage.png" />
    <meta property="og:url" content="/social/post/facebook.aspx">
    <meta property="og:type" content="myapp:myobname" />
    <meta property="og:description" content="Praesent neque velit, ultrices" />
```

So, if anybody has any idea what I'm doing wrong, please let me know.

Comment: You forgot to show how exactly you are _making_ the post …

Comment: I’m not sure if you can give title and description as parameters when publishing an _action_ on an Open Graph object (that’s something different then a normal link post). And a relative og:url is most likely an error too, so make that an absolute one (and then check your object using the debug tool).

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that this was a caching issue.  Following the instructions here: [Facebook Open Graph not clearing cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5776567/facebook-open-graph-not-clearing-cache) resolved this for me.