# Facebook Payments - cannot reset product description cache

Tags: facebook, caching, product

Once created product descripion html-file I could not wipe out from facebook cache. These methods didn't help:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/payments/definingproducts/#scraping
[Facebook Open Graph not clearing cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5776567/facebook-open-graph-not-clearing-cache)
Buy-product-window old icon when I scraped and even delete product file on my server.

Comment: Found the problem. New image was too small (less then 200x200) so facebook was using old bigger image.

Answer (score 0):

Scraping the og:product object

Once you have defined an og:product object, you must force a scrape of your Open Graph object using the debug tool, or by issuing an http request to the Graph API endpoint below. You must also force a re-scrape with one of these methods if you modify your og:product object, signifying to Facebook that the cache needs to be updated.

GET https://graph.facebook.com/?id=OBJECT_URL&scrape=true&method=post

Here, OBJECT_URL is the public URL where your object can be found on the internet, the same value as used in og:url in your object metadata. Be sure to URL encode OBJECT_URL when using it in the Graph API call above so that any query parameters are interpreted correctly.

Source : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/payments/product