# Fetch New Open Graph Image - Facebook

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

I have the following problem.

I have a social plugin on a particular website, and every day the thumbnail images (Image Open Graph) are changed.

Every day I need to enter the following url:

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/

And insert my url, and click "Fetch new Scrape Information".

To update the facebook Open Graph Image.

Does anyone know how to automate this process?

Comment: Essentially, if you are sharing the same thing then the thumbnails should not change. Perhaps you should consider setting up special URL for each change in the content - perhaps inserting the date into the URL.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Solution:

[Facebook - Open Graph not clearing cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5776567/facebook-open-graph-not-clearing-cache/21468084#21468084)

Add to your page:

```
$.post(
    'https://graph.facebook.com',
    {
        id: '<?php echo $url; ?>',
        scrape: true
    },
    function(response){
        console.log(response);
    }
);
```