# How to batch my entire sitemap with Facebook Debug?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have an ecommerce and I need to batch my entire product catalogue (~200 pages) because we did some modification on the og:image.

I use this tool : https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/ but it takes a life to add the url and click "Fetch new scrape information" for every url of my sitemap.

Any ways to do this faster?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can refresh the OG data with a post request, here´s an example with jQuery:

```
$.post('https://graph.facebook.com', {
    id: 'https://yourdomain.com/somepermalink',
    scrape: true
}, function(response) {
    console.log(response);
});
```

Of course you can also use PHP CURL requests and do this with a PHP script only.

Source: [Facebook Open Graph not clearing cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5776567/facebook-open-graph-not-clearing-cache/21468084#21468084)