# Facebook Open Graph: After have fetched new scrapes, the displayed existing scrape still wrong

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I got the follwing issue:

in [FB Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/), I put the link to be refreshed.
  [This is the page](http://www.melanie-music.net/videos/piensa-en-mi)

Once have clicked on "***Fetch new scrape information***", I get the new data, totally correct.

I verify it into the field "***When shared, this is what will be included***". Not any error/warning occurred.

The issue is: when I click to "***Show existing scrape information***", I still get old data.

And worse: when I share the link, the old data are still shared :-/

I have not clue how to solve this issue ...

**EDIT**
I also tried the solutions proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5776567/facebook-open-graph-not-clearing-cache) but all failed

**EDIT 2**
I give here some graphical example taken with Snipping tool
Here what FB Debug fetched:

[image]

Clearly it says "when shared this is what will be included"

Then I try to share it and it seems good

[image]

but once posted

[image]

The description and title is totally missing

Thus back to Debugger and clicking on show "existing scrape"
and i see that unfortunately, wrong data are kept

[image]

Comment: Likely some sort of caching … wait a few days, and then try again.

Comment: but the Debugger should serve to refresh the cache.
It's the first time I get this issue. Normally in all te other pages, once I clicked on"Fetch new scrape", the cache is renewed and the new content is taken. In this case it seems that the new content is succesfully analyzed and detected, but it's ignored for some reason

Comment: I edited and posted some screenshot, in order to give an idea about what it's happening. I also added the link to the real page, so that you can see the code and make some experiment. I'm still trying with code's modifications to understand why it behaves so

Comment: That is a different issue – when showing the full-size video thumbnail, Facebook seems to have decided lately to drop the title and description in some cases in news feed view; when you go to the individual post you should be able to see them however.

Comment: The problem is that: if I share the direct channel from youtube, FB is showing correctly, while  from the site not. When I post, I mean I click on "post" it drops title and description. The same occurs, when after have clicked on "Fetch new scrape information", I click on "Show existing scrape information" ... and I'm not able to make it accept Title and Description, which are quite important for such material

Comment: They _are_ “accepted”, but just not _shown_. As I said, it looks like Facebook decided to do this in some cases a while ago, and there is nothing you can do about it.

Comment: As I said, if I post the direct URL of YouTUBE, the Title and Description are kept.
Please here the direct link to try with: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NnoBLtPdW_E
That's struggles me, because if FB decided as you told, it should be valid for all the links, instead of it seems it's different

Comment: When I share that youtube link, I only get a small square thumbnail – and in that case, Facebook shows title and description next to it. But full-size thumbnails they seem to be handling different nowadays.

Comment: Right, I want to replicate the case you also got and that the fetcher shows (but not keeps): the small thumbnail with the description

Comment: Facebook decides which version to show when, where and to whom. There is nothing that I know of that you can do to influence this.

Comment: I found the solution and perhaps I understood the reason of this issue. Please you find it in a second post, following the first one :)

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the solution.

the "bug" is into this line of my template:

```
 <meta property="og:image" content="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/{$video_code}/maxresdefault.jpg" />
```

were `{$video_code}` is changed by PHP with the code of the video, in this specific case `NnoBLtPdW_E`

This line, address to a picture YouTUBE generates, and it's the videothumbnail.
When this line is into the metatag, which is out of my domain, FB seems dislike it and chooses to show directly the video,

**without**:

- any alert
- returning errors
- and not during the fetching at all, nor the sending to the UI, but
  only once this is sent

Even trying to add the following tags:

```
<meta property="og:image:width" content="200" />
<meta property="og:image:height" content="200" />
```

it was totally useless

But removing the line "og:image" and adding a local thumbnail, solved the issue
here the line solved the issue:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.melanie-music.net/{$directory_pictures}/{$song_dir}/vthumb.jpg" />
```

I do hope this experience will be useful to anybody else that faced out the same problem.