# Facebook Open Graph Debug not updating scrape mobile - no app caching

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, caching

I ran into a little issue earlier. I have a YouTube video whose title needed to be changed. We jumped onto Facbook Debugger to update the scrape information. This worked for most instances and the title is now pulled through correctly.

However, on some mobile Facebook apps the scrape information is still the old one (Samsung/ Sony Android). This doesn't change even when the app's cache is emptied.

We even tried the solution described here, but to no avail (fbrefresh=CAN_BE_ANYTHING): [Facebook Open Graph not clearing cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5776567/facebook-open-graph-not-clearing-cache)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. So I figured it out.

Facebook caches YouTube URLs from the browser URL bar and URLs from YouTube's sharing feature separately. Both need to be debugged separately to ensure that all shared links are up to date.