# og meta tags not working on compiled vuejs project

Tags: vue.js, webpack, facebook-opengraph, meta-tags

I'm working on a project generated with vue CLI 3, i went to the public folder and inserted the following meta tags inside the head:

```
<meta property="og:site_name" content="My Site">
<meta property="og:title" content="My Site" />
<meta property="og:description" content="Description" />
<meta property="og:image" itemprop="image" content="http://mysiteurl.com/image.jpg">
<meta property="og:type" content="website"/>
```

But they doesnt work on FB or Whatsapp, where i have to make them work.
What am i doing wrong?

Comment: what's the error? `<meta>` tags don't show after you run `npm run build`?

Comment: Oh yeah, they show, i inspected the source code and they're right there, but when i share the page via Whatsapp i don,t see the description or the image.

Comment: Ah, then you need [something like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5776567/facebook-open-graph-not-clearing-cache). You need to either wait or use the answer from the link to force FB to clear the cache