# Wordpress - How do I remove meta og:image that contain broken link?

Tags: php, wordpress, function, meta-tags

I have many tags that I think not everything useful and make my sites slow. some of the tags has broken link
I have these tags:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="https://sakindo.co.id/94957/2019/09/Banner-Trading-Import.jpg" />
<meta property="og:image" content="https://sakindo.co.id/94957/2019/09/Banner-Barang-Branded-1.png" />
<meta property="og:image" content="https://sakindo.co.id/94957/2018/04/offer_banner_21.png" />
<meta property="og:image" content="https://sakindo.co.id/94957/2018/04/offer_banner_31.png" />
<meta property="og:image" content="https://sakindo.co.id/94957/2018/04/offer_banner_41.png" />
<meta property="og:image" content="https://sakindo.co.id/94957/2019/11/HITAM-SURF-A-1-150x150.jpg" />
and many many many more.....
```

How do I remove that `meta` tags?

Comment: Q: Where exactly are you seeing these meta tags?  "View source" in a web browser?  Q: Which pages on your Wordpress site are they appearing in?

Comment: might be this will be helpful for you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5776567/facebook-open-graph-not-clearing-cache

Comment: @paulsm4 A: Yes, it appears on View Source on Landing page. Some of that links are broken cause the image has been deleted.

Comment: @NealDeveloper Hmm, seems like not affect for me. That ```meta``` still appears on View Source.

Comment: The reason why worried me is my site has noticed Bad Request by GT Metrix & Google Page Speed, and made my sites slow. Theirs recommend me to removes them

Answer (score 1):

There is not much info here.
I am assuming these meta tags are coming from some plugin.

If it's an SEO plugin then make sure settings are correct.
OR
If the plugin is buggy then disable that and try.
OR
Find what function responsible for adding these tags. Using some hook you can override its functionality of rendering meta tags like this.

Let me know if that makes sense. Thanks.

Comment: I don't know where they came from. I've tried to make sure the SEO plugin that I used. But the ```meta``` still appear at "View Source"

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution for this problem (Maybe).
Just install this plugin [Broken Link Checker](https://wordpress.org/plugins/broken-link-checker/)