# Facebook Graph API - Get ID from Facebook Page URL

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3581488/facebook-graph-api-get-id-for-a-url) but what I want is different.

I want to get the Facebook ID not from a general URL (and therefore conditional if it has Like button or not). I want to get the Facebook ID given a Facebook page using the Graph API.

Notice that Facebook pages can have several formats, such as:

```
http://www.facebook.com/my_page_name
http://www.facebook.com/pages/my_page_name
http://www.facebook.com/my_page_ID
```

I know I could do some regex to get either the my_page name or my_page_ID, but I am wondering if any one know if GraphAPI is supporting what I want.

Comment: It's worth noting that although the Facebook API specifies that pages are looked up via {page-id} and that the ID is a "numeric string", the text name seems to work equally well.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

It seems to me that the easiest solution to what you describe is to just get the id/name from the url you have using *lastIndexOf("/")* (which most languages have an equivalent for) and then get *"https://graph.facebook.com/" + id*.

The data that this url returns has the id (i.e.: 6708787004) and the username (i.e.: southpark), so regardless of which identifier you use (what you extract from the url using lastIndexOf), you should get the same result.

---

## Edit

This code:

```
identifier = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf("/"))
graphUrl = "https://graph.facebook.com/" + identifier
urlJsonData = getGraphData(graphUrl)
```

Should work the same (that is result with the same data) for both:

```
url = http://www.facebook.com/southpark
```

And

```
url = http://www.facebook.com/6708787004
```

(you'll obviously need to implement the *getGraphData* method).

Also, the 2nd url form in the question is not a valid url for pages, at least not from my tests, I get:

> You may have clicked an expired link or mistyped the address. Some web
>   addresses are case sensitive.

Comment: can you please explain this more this is also useful for me 
i understand what you mean but i didn't get the id or name using lastindexof()
can you please give the complete code

Comment: This doesn't always work. I'm looking at a page whose URL has the form http://www.facebook.com/pages/<Name>/<Number>. I tried asking for graph.facebook.com/<Number>, but I get an error: {
  "error": {
    "message": "Unsupported get request.", 
    "type": "GraphMethodException", 
    "code": 100
  }
}. Using the whole path doesn't work either. This is an unpublished page created by a test user (I'm trying to test an app that needs to get page ids programmatically).

Comment: @NitzanTomer This works: graph.facebook.com/<Number>

Comment: @NitzanTomer This code won't work if the URL ends with a trailing slash. Which the event URLs in Facebook all seem to have now.

Comment: This doesn't work anymore ? If you go to http://graph.facebook.com/my_name, it says it requires an access token.

Comment: This method will work with a short-term user access token, which has been granted interactively, but won't work using an app access token or a test user access token.

Comment: Both works for me. But the reason to get fb id rather than name because the name can be changed. If I store "southpark" in my database later the owner change it to "southparkOfficial", I can't get to access this page using fb name "southpark".

Answer (score 10):

The answer to the question is posted above but the method shown below works fine we do not have to perform the `regex` on the facebook page urls

I got the answer by this method

```
FB.api('/any_fb_page_url', function(response){
  console.log(response);
});
```

any_fb_page_url can be any of the following types

```
https://www.facebook.com/my_page_name
https://www.facebook.com/pages/my_page_name
https://www.facebook.com/my_page_ID
```

This are also listed in question above

This code is tested on JS console available on [Facebook Developers site tools](https://developers.facebook.com)

Answer (score 6):

You can get the page id by using the below api

https://graph.facebook.com/v2.7/smhackapp?fields=id,name,fan_count,picture,is_verified&access_token=**access_token**&format=json

[Reference image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yqP5z.png)

Comment: Works just fine. Don't forget to replace `access_token` with a valid token.

Answer (score 6):

This answer is updated and checked in 2019:
and it is very simple because you do not need to extract anything from the link. for examples:

1. https://www.facebook.com/pg/Vaireo-Shop-2138395226250622/about/
2. https://www.facebook.com/withminta
3. https://www.facebook.com/2138395226250622

https://graph.facebook.com/?id=link&access_token=xxxxxxxx

response:
{
    "name": "Vaireo Shop",
    "id": "2138395226250622"
}

full nodeJS answer:

```
async function getBusinessFromFBByPageURL(pageURL: string) {
    const accessToken = process.env.fb_app_access_token;
    const graphUrl = `https://graph.facebook.com/?id=${pageURL}? access_token=${accessToken}`;
    const fbGraphResponse = await Axios.get(graphUrl);
```

Comment: Can any Facebook URL be passed directly into the API and that will return a profile object?

Answer (score 5):

```
<?php

function getFacebookId($url) {

    $id =  substr(strrchr($url,'/'),1); 

    $json = file_get_contents('http://graph.facebook.com/'.$id);

    $json = json_decode($json);

    return $json->id;

}


echo getFacebookId($_GET['url']);


?>
```

Thats a PHP example of how to get the ID.

Comment: How do you know that you will always get url having facebook page id. There might be page name instead of page id. What will you do in that case?

Answer (score 1):

As of Nov 26 2021 none of these solutions work.
Facebook has locked down the API so you need an App Review.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/pages/overview/permissions-features#features

Answer (score 0):

This answer takes into account that a URL can end with a trailing slash, something that Facebook event pages seem to have in their URLs now.

```
function getId(url) {
  var path = new URL(url).pathname;
  var parts = path.split('/');

  parts = parts.filter(function(part) {
    return part.length !== 0;
  });

  return parts[parts.length - 1];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can Use **Requests** and **re** Modules in **python**

Code:

```
import requests,re

profile_url = "https://www.facebook.com/alanwalker97"

idre = re.complie('"entity_id":"([0-9]+)"')

con = requests.get(profile_url).content

id = idre.findall(con)

print("\n[*] ID: "+id[0])
```

Output:

> [*] ID: 100001013078780

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps you can look through the https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/#searching docs: search against a couple of types and if you find what you're looking for go from there.